# How to catch NullRefenceException in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am debuggin a subtle bug that is thrown from a .net custom component (no source and obfuscated). The component throws a NullReferenceException in its OnPaint() method which makes calls to subscribers, including my code. I am 100% sure that the problem is in my code. The problem is that visual studio debugger does not stop at the point where the exception is thrown, as it should (I enabled NullReferenceException in the Debug/Exceptions dialog).

This is the first time I encountered such a problem in visual studio. Any ideas on identifying offending code, please?

Kemal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the problem is your code isn't throwing the `NullReferenceException`, however it is probably returning `null` at some point. You could try adding guard conditions at the end of your functions that ensure you are not returning `null`, such as an `Debug.Assert(retVal != null, "Returned null in function")`.

If you are sure you own code is throwing a `NullReferenceException`, make sure you turn on thrown exceptions, rather than user-unhandled ones.

Comment: yes, it is likely that my code at some point returns a value that is inconsistent with the expected values from the component, and some null return values are legal. 
Is there a way to put a breakpoint into binaries?

Comment: @Kemal Erdogan: Yes but it involves breaking on either IL or native commands.